# Read O365 Group Members from O365 with VBA-Excel using Graph API or other APIs

Tags: excel, vba

It's my first attempt to call a Graph API (with VBA Excel). I need a full code example how to read the members of a o365 Group an theire paramters, like last logon time etc.

The goal ist to read all user from a specific group and list them in a excel file row by row. The Colum schould contain values like name, sammaccountname, Last Logon date etc.

Also Important ist the way to grant accees for the external request.
What I understood ist that I have to get a token, from the Graph API and than I can reag the membership of groups.

Nothing tried so far. Yust try to find the right code example to start.